# Filesystem becomes read-only after almost every restart and have to run fsck /dev/sdb every time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, fsck

This started happening last week. I have an HDD and an SSD. The Ubuntu 20.04 is on the HDD and Windows 10 on SSD and have been using this for more than 2 years without any problem. Last week, suddenly the terminal was not working and saying that the files were read-only. After some google searches, I found a way around this and restarted to a live USB and ran the `fsck /dev/sdb6` and `fsck /dev/sdb7`commands and got rid of this problem. But after that almost every time I restart the machine there is an error with the disks. Sometimes it just get stuck on the dell logo screen or sometimes takes to the initfram terminal and have to do the fsck with live usb. Sometimes I have to do this more than once. This is becoming more and more annoying. There is another thing to mention that if I try to see the partitions using GParted it shows that there is an error reading partitions on sdb.
sda is the ssd. sdb is the hdd. There are 4 partitions in the hdd; 2 are ntfs and used by windows 10, the other two contains the root(/) and /home.
I've been searching for this error and found the suggestion that the hdd is dying. I have no problem to use the hdd partitions on windows. So I am not sure what is happening here or How can I diagnose.

**Edit:**
I've run the `CHKDSK` and `wmic diskdrive get model,status` on the windows and they retured:

```
Model               Status
TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100  OK
HP SSD S600 240GB   OK
```

and

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  1893888 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 1.44 minutes.
  14843 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.78 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  18637 reparse records processed.
  2471016 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 4.01 minutes.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 38.53 seconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.42 milliseconds.
  18637 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 80.19 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 133.20 milliseconds.
  288565 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 0.71 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  36967352 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
 Phase duration (USN journal verification): 680.75 milliseconds.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 233864555 KB total disk space.
 169107708 KB in 1525127 files.
    765556 KB in 288566 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   2007563 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  61983728 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  58466138 total allocation units on disk.
  15495932 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 6.11 minutes (366875 ms).
```

Checked the hdd with CrystalDiskInfo too and it looks like this. Now I am confused as the some checks shows errors and some don't.
[image: CrystalDiskInfo Status]

Comment: Indeed classic symptoms of a dying HDD. That a different partition encounters no problems (yet) is normal. Sooner or later it will. Look up how to run SMART test on your hard drive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've checked using multiple methods. The command line check and sentinel app didn't show any error or warning. But CrystalDiskInfo app showed cuation for hdd. I am not sure what should I understand for these.